# Javac producing error with no origin

Tags: ant, compiler-errors, javac

I am using javac in ant to compile a project and I am getting an compilation error message without the file or line number. Why is this and how can i find where in the (large) project the problem is?

```
build.xml

make_folders:

compile:
[javac] Compiling 33 source files to *project root*/bin/classes
[javac] error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Integer
[javac] Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
[javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
*project root*/build.xml:33: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

And heres the relevant lines with verbose set to true:

```
[javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/util/Date.class)]]
[javac] error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Integer
```

UPDATE:
So I managed to figure out that the error it was originating from calling a function in a class from within an inner class in said outer class. I'm not sure why this produced an error or why it was presented with such little information so any help would still be appreciated.

Comment: Insert `<compilerarg value="-Xdiags:verbose"/>` under the `<javac>` in the build.xml. This should provide clearer info about the source of the error.